# Post results increases on each change event

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

I am making an ajax POST to a servlet which returns me an array. The call is triggered on an onchange event. For the first time I receive the correct data. But from there onwards, the data keeps adding up.

For example first time onchange event occurs and array received contains [10,11] which is correct.

Second time onchange event occurs but array received contains [10,11,12,13] when it should have been just [12,13]. Thir change event will be an even longer set of data.

I tried with cache: false and same results. Please advice.

```
$('#drivername1').on('change', function() {
    $.post("statChartServlet", {driverName : this.value},  function(responseText) {
        alert(responseText); //this is the array data that keeps increasing
    });
});
```

Servlet

```
private ArrayList<String> tempArr = new ArrayList<String>();
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                          HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String driverName = request.getParameter("driverName");

        Connection conn = null;

        try{
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbUser, dbPass);

            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultset =
                    statement.executeQuery("select racename from race WHERE drivername = '" + driverName + "'");

            while(resultset.next()) {
                tempArr.add(resultset.getString(1));
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        //response section
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        String[] strArr = tempArr.toArray(new String[tempArr.size()]);
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.write(Arrays.toString(strArr));
    }
```

Comment: what is it processing server side ? a bit more info on the use case of this process might be useful since it might not be a technical issue, rather a code bug in the server processing

Comment: @H.B I have added the back end for Servlet above in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line right here `private ArrayList<String> tempArr = new ArrayList<String>();`

It persists between requests. Put it inside `doPost`. Ideally, servlets should be stateless, to prevent bugs like this.

Comment: Nope. The servlet stays alive forever... or until the webapp is taken offline. So that arraylist is available to all requests.

Comment: Thanks eric. Never knew servlets will do that.